# WP /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php produces 404

Tags: menus, ajax, wp-admin

Our site has been working fine in the last week. Today, I can't add a new page to our menu. Clicking "Add to Menu" just produces a spinning icon that never disappears.

If I look at the Chrome console, I see:

> POST
>   https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_fs_blog_admin=true
>   404 (Not Found)

There are no restrictions on `/wp-admin` or `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` in `/.htaccess` or `/wp-admin/.htaccess`.

I've Googled for this problem but most Q&A post relate to custom ajax calls.

In our case we're not making custom ajax calls.

Troubleshooting steps appreciated.

PS - I am waiting on the web host to check if `mod_security` is causing this issue.

Comment: Have you verified the file is unmodified and intact? And that the rest of the core WP files are unmodified? This is highly unusual

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, I uploaded a fresh copy of admin-ajax.php and that solved the problem straight away. Add an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` might have been modified by another php file or plugin. Try downloading a copy of your wordpress version and overwrite `admin-ajax.php` with the original source file. 
If that doesn't work, try deactivating your plugins (or theme) one by one until you notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have descovered that for me this occurs because my script has a long run time chrome has a 5 minute timeout period. The script is ajax and keeps running even when the browser gives up on it. Oh I just saw you are not dealing with a custom ajax call, in that case this will not help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255238)